# Block direct HTTP access to a PHP File

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php script which I want to run only from the command prompt, and want it to be blocked over HTTP. How should I do it?

What I have tried:

```
define('CLI_SCRIPT', true);
```

It did not help me a lot, was still able to open the file.

Adding to .htaccess:

```
DENY FROM ALL
```

It blocks the file from all source, even from the command prompt.

**I cannot place it outside the public_html. I don't have access to other folders of the server.**

Comment: "It blocks the file from all source, even from the command prompt." Uh, no, that's not possible, unless you're doing something like `curl http://example.com/script.php`, in which case you should just be doing `php script.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to exit early if the return value is not `"cli"`.

```
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
    exit();
}
```